# how to mark any class type in jsdoc for type hints

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

I write some functions, like this:

```
/**
 * Throw TypeError when val is invalid
 * @param {JOIN_TYPES} type
 * @param {Class|Function} cls
 * @param {*} val
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {String} options.wrongJoinTypeErrorMessage
 * @param {Boolean} options.nullable
 */
function validateJoinSet(type, cls, val, options) {
//...
}
```

I want to mark some parameter that it is some class not any function,
I do this this way:

```
 * @param {Class|Function} cls
```

But when I expect type hints, idea tells me "**Class**" not found.
How to do this with jsdoc in intellij idea?

Answer (score 1):

`class` keyword in EcmaScript6 is only sugar around function and its prototype. It still returns function

```
class A {}
console.log(typeof A == 'function');
```

So, there is no need to specify class explicitly, anyway the function `validateJoinSet` will get constructor function as argument, and you can describe it just as `Function`.